# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException как исправить?

Tags: java, apache, javafx, io

Только начал разбираться в javafx и сразу же столкнулся с проблемой,просто перенес проект из java и добавил listview, только вот все пошло не по плану.Как исправить это дело?

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;


import java.lang.String;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.parser.Parser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.mp3.Mp3Parser;




public class Main extends Application {



    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        String fileLocation = "D:\\music";
        File dir = new File(fileLocation);
        readFiles(dir);



        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Radio");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 1000));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }


    public static void readFiles(File baseDirectory) {

        List<Mp3data> mp3data = new ArrayList<Mp3data>();
        ObservableList<Mp3data> langs = FXCollections.observableArrayList(mp3data);
        ListView<Mp3data> langsListView = new ListView<Mp3data>(langs);

        try {

            Iterator<File> iterator = FileUtils.iterateFiles(baseDirectory, new String[]{"mp3"}, true);
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                File fileloop = iterator.next();


                InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileloop);
                ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
                Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
                ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
                parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);


                input.close();

                String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();


                Mp3data track = new Mp3data();
                track.setArtist(metadata.get("xmpDM:artist"));
                track.setAlbum(metadata.get("xmpDM:album"));
                track.setTitle(metadata.get("title"));
                track.setDuration(toMinutes(metadata.get("xmpDM:duration")));
                track.setPath(fileloop.getAbsolutePath());

                mp3data.add(track);
                langs.add(track);


            }
            FlowPane root = new FlowPane(langsListView);
            Collections.sort(mp3data);

        } catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


//        String artist = null;
//        String album = null;
//        for (Mp3data data : mp3data)
//            if (!data.getArtist().equals(artist))
//
//
//
//                if (!data.getAlbum().equals(album))



    }

    public static String toMinutes(String timeInMilis) {
        double milis = Double.valueOf(timeInMilis);
        long second = (long) (milis / 1000) % 60;
        long minute = (long) (milis / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
        long hour = (long) (milis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
        return hour != 0 ? String.format("%02dh:%02dm:%02ds", hour, minute, second) : String.format("%02dm:%02ds", minute, second);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот собственно ошибки

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/util/IOUtils
    at org.apache.tika.parser.mp3.MpegStream.skipFrame(MpegStream.java:164)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.mp3.Mp3Parser.getAllTagHandlers(Mp3Parser.java:212)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.mp3.Mp3Parser.parse(Mp3Parser.java:70)
    at sample.Main.readFiles(Main.java:82)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:46)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/util/IOUtils где apache io потеряли?

Comment: а где он должен быть?

Comment: Поидее в библиотеке commons-io-2.6. Посмотрите, есть ли он там

Comment: добавил poi 2.6.1.jar ошибка пропала но теперь новая Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.skipFully(Ljava/io/InputStream;J)J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключил библиотеку poi 2.6.1 jar исправил ошибку, но появилась новая

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:502)
    at sample.Main.toMinutes(Main.java:121)
    at sample.Main.readFiles(Main.java:86)
    at sample.Main.lambda$start$0(Main.java:43)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```